# Python 3 Read a json file with missing objects within lines

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm reading a json file with the structure below:

```
    [{"id":1,"gender":"Male","first_name":"Andrew","last_name":"Scott","email":"ascott0@shutterfly.com","ville":"Connecticut"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Mary","last_name":"Richards","email":"mrichards2@japanpost.jp","ville":"Minnesota"}]
```

So, as you can see in the second "line" the field "gender" it'is not present.I realize that because my code to read the file got wrong in this line.

my code:

```
import json

def jsonreader():
##Reader for json files
    ##Open files using json library
    with open('cust_data.json') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    resultlist = list()
    for line in data:
        print(line["id"],line["gender"])
```

I got the error:-

```
C:/xxxxx/x.py
1 Male
Traceback (most recent call last):
2 Female
File "C:/xxxxx/x", line 67, in <module>
jsonreader()
File "C:/xxxxx/x", line 56, in jsonreader
print(line["id"],line["gender"])
KeyError: 'gender'
```

Before answer guys, you should know that I have a method to define the default value in "gender", voila my method:

```
def definegender(x):
    if x is None:
        x = 'unknown'
        return x
    elif (x =='Male') or (x=='Female'):#not None:
        return {
         'Male':'M',
         'Female': 'F'
        }.get(x)
    else:
        return x
```

So, in this case, I could not use something like a default value reading the values because I need to send some value to my method.

Some one of you guys would know how should be the best way to read this kind of files when we have missing objects. Thanks

Comment: Before answer guys, you should know that I have a method to define the default value in "gender", voila my method:

Comment: What you are asking for is not clear. You have a method to always give gender field a value, but your json has no gender field in some cases. Now, you want handle these cases (that should never happens due to your `definegender()`), but don't want to use error handling nor default values... so, what's the results do you expect?

Comment: @mrnfrancesco here is the thing. I need to read the file and check line by line the fields to create a class object called "person" so to ensure that always the gender is M or F or UNKNOWN I created this method. the thing is that i can't just pass the field to my method cuz sometimes it's not coming from the source file. :(

Comment: Then just use: `print(line["id"],definegender(line.get("gender")))`

In this way you get the gender from the dict if it exists, otherwise None. Giving it to your function does the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this already has a perfect answer, my point of view is that there can be alternatives too. So here it is:

```
for line in data:
    try:
        print(line["id"],line["gender"])
    except KeyError:
        print(line["id"],"Error!!! no gender!")
```

This is called ErrorHandling. Read the docs here:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html

---

**update**: Do you mean this?
**update2** *corrected misstake*

```
try:
    gender = definegender(line["gender"])
except KeyError:
    gender = definegender(None)
print(line["id"],gender)
```

---

**update3**: (for future purposes)

as .get() returns None by default the most simple solution would be

```
gender = definegender(line.get("gender"))
print(line["id"],gender)
```

Comment: look my edition about how to play with the method to validate the gender. thanks

Comment: ok @AndresAngel I looked and updated my answer. Although I am not 100% sure what you are asking for.

Comment: you right the thing is that I'm trying to create a "human" object from a class using this for loop to read the json file. I will try your approach thanks buddy

Comment: thanks so much buddy I guess I figure it out with your approach. awesome

Comment: @AntonvBR the code in your update is wrong. The default value for gender when it is not present or equals to `None` is `"unkown"`, but your solution just print `None` instead

Answer (score 6):

why not using a default value for your dictionary in `dict.get`?

```
print(line["id"],line.get("gender","unknown"))
```

And since you want to transform input further, you could nest two `dict.get` together, the first one with `None` as default value, and a new table, like this:

```
gender_dict = {"Male":"M", "Female":"F", None : "unknown"}

print(line["id"],gender_dict.get(line.get("gender")))
```

(note that you don't need your overcomplex gender conversion method anymore)

Comment: I have just to add another detail in my question cuz I need run a method to set a default value for gender. thanks

Comment: @AndresAngel I think my new edit will suit you (and is simpler than your original method)

Answer (score 1):

Why not simplify this with an if-statement?

```
for line in data:
    if "gender" in line:
        print(line)
```

Comment: look my edition post about how to play with the method to validate the gender. thanks